# Dehydrating eggs

Tags: eggs, dehydrating, camping

I have seen a few examples of dehydrating scrambled eggs, and reconstituting them later. It got me wondering if there is a way to dehydrate raw eggs in a way that lets them still work for baking.

I think it would be a good way to make a "just add milk" pancake mix for camping, so we don't have to bring eggs along.

Is there a good method for dehydrating eggs in a standard home dehydrator, and will they be usable for baking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Powdered eggs](http://shop.honeyville.com/powdered-whole-eggs.html) are available for purchase.  Yes, they can be used for baking.  Due to the their advantages, they are often advertised for camping or long-term storage use.  You can even purchase the powdered whites and powdered yolks separately.  However, there are many applications they are not good for (fried eggs, anyone?).

There are a number of tutorials online about dehydrating raw eggs at home, but there are also warnings of salmonella because home dehydrators may leave the eggs in the food safety danger zone for too long.

Comment: "some dehydrators may leave the eggs in the food safety danger zone too long" - the eggs will either be smack in the middle of the danger zone, or they will get cooked. Assuming that no egg will go dry in less than 2 hours (they have lots of moisture and home dehydrators are not very efficient) you cannot safely dehydrate eggs at home.

Comment: Wow - I completely forgot about powdered eggs. Those should work perfectly.

Comment: Theoretically, if the eggs were mixed and spread thin enough and not overly crowded, you might be able to dry them within 2 hours, though they may just cook anyway. I wouldn't recommend attempting it, though.

Comment: Also, a freeze dryer might be confused with a dehydrator by some, and ["home freeze dryers"](http://www.amazon.com/Freeze-Dryer----Harvest-Right/dp/B00JRH8IEC/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1422744103&sr=8-1&keywords=home+freeze+dryer) have recently come on the market. Freeze drying would be a viable method of safely 'dehydrating' eggs, though you'd have to use it a whole lot to make it worth the huge expense of the equipment.